# Locating the C header "stdio.h"

Tags: compiling, c, programming

I wrote my first C program which is the generic "hello world" program. Could anyone please tell me where can I find `stdio.h` file in my system? It will help me a lot in understanding of the language.

Comment: Do you want to locate the file to look at it, or do you have some _other_ issue relating to not finding it?

Comment: I very much doubt reading the system header files will be of much use to a normal user. There's too much compatibility stuff there, for different systems and settings. Also, the header file doesn't contain the implementations of the library functions themselves, it's just the function declarations etc. If you want to see the implementations, I suggest you start with some alternative, more minimal C library, instead of glibc. (I think uclibc and musl are the two.)

Comment: Seriously why does this get a "needs more clarity vote"?  That's "Where is this specific I file on my system?" Is flagged as somehow unclear?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu, which your original question indicated you’re using, the “root” `stdio.h` file is in `/usr/include`. Other systems may put it elsewhere, and in all cases it’s likely that `stdio.h` pulls in other files.

You’ll probably find it more helpful to read [the POSIX specification for `stdio.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html), and then look at how your system implements that. On Linux, [`man 3 stdio`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) also provides a useful summary; other systems have similar documentation.

Comment: Thank you Steven !

Answer (score 2):

It's system-dependent (note that [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html) does not specify location of header-files, nor does the C standard).  Conventionally, it would be found in `/usr/include`.  However, on some systems (even those ***having*** a `/usr/include` directory), it may not be found there.

For instance, recent (the past few years) macOS SDKs put this in a directory under the SDK (just like Visual Studio...).  Looking for `stdio.h` on one of my machines gives this list for example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk/System/DriverKit/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
/opt/local/include/gcc/c++/tr1/stdio.h
/opt/local/include/gcc8/c++/tr1/stdio.h
/opt/local/include/gcc9/c++/tr1/stdio.h
/opt/local/include/isc/stdio.h
/opt/local/lib/gcc8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/opt/local/lib/gcc8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.3.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
/opt/local/lib/gcc9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/opt/local/lib/gcc9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-9.0/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-9.0/lib/c++/v1/stdio.h
```

The files under `/opt` are for MacPorts (a third-party).

Even when the file is ***in*** `/usr/include`, most of its content (implementation details) may be in another file.  The internal-details may be in a subdirectory of `/usr/include` (Solaris), or they may not (usually not).  Again, macOS is an example, but there are others.  Without details on the system involved, no one can give a detailed answer.

Usually (again, not always), your compiler and its associated C preprocessor can help find the actual file which is used.  You'll have to consult the appropriate documentation, but this worked for me with macOS for the hello-world program:

```
/usr/bin/clang -E hello.c >hello.log
```

which (is a little too long for an answer) begins thus:

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "" 1
# 1 "" 3
# 366 "" 3
# 1 "" 1
# 1 "" 2
# 1 "hello.c" 2
# 1 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 64 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 68 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
...
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas !!